# Replacing list elements while preserving their attributes

Tags: r, r-s3

Consider the following list:

```r
lst <- list(
  a = structure("x", class = "foo", type = "bar"),
  b = "y"
)
str(lst)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: 'foo' chr "x"
#>   ..- attr(*, "type")= chr "bar"
#>  $ b: chr "y"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would like to preserve the attributes when replacing elements of class `foo` with another value.
Basically I'd like a method that replicates the following behavior:

```r
res <- (function(x, i, value) {
  attrs <- attributes(x[[i]])
  x[[i]] <- value
  attributes(x[[i]]) <- attrs
  x
})(lst, "a", "z")

str(res)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: 'foo' chr "z"
#>   ..- attr(*, "type")= chr "bar"
#>  $ b: chr "y"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

How can I do that? I guess the solution is to implement a `` `[[<-.foo` `` method but can't figure out how to make it work? As far as I understand this kind of method will use the class of `lst`, not that of the elements it contains.

I'm looking for a base R solution only.

Comment: I'm not sure from your example whether something as straightforward as `lst[["a"]][] <- "z"` would work?

Comment: For some reasons I though that `_[] <-` only preserved the `names` attribute, not everything. This is definitely the most straightforward solution and works perfectly in my case. Could you please make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `lst[["a"]]` can be changed, while keeping its attributes using `lst[["a"]][] <- "z"`.

```
#Example data
lst <- list(
  a = structure("x", class = "foo", type = "bar"),
  b = "y"
)
str(lst)
#List of 2
# $ a: 'foo' chr "x"
#  ..- attr(*, "type")= chr "bar"
# $ b: chr "y"

#Change element a, while keeping attributes
lst[["a"]][] <- "z"
str(lst)
#List of 2
# $ a: 'foo' chr "z"
#  ..- attr(*, "type")= chr "bar"
# $ b: chr "y"
```